# DateTime Custom Formatting for Seasons

Tags: c#

I've come across a problem customizing my DateTimePicker value in my application.  I've read all about the various formatting strings which you can use to customize the way the date/time is interpreted.  The issue is that I actually want some of the text to be ignored in the custom format string so that I can add in the season as a string to the beginning of the DateTimePicker.

For example, let's take today's date which is August 7th, 2013 at 5:30PM (in the US). If I use the custom format string *"MMM.d  -h:mm tt"* then the date will be shown as Aug. 7th - 5:30PM.  So, that's perfect.  Only, I want to add the season to the beginning of the string.  So, in this case, it would be "**Summer: Aug. 7th - 5:30PM**".

The issue that I'm having is that if I insert the word "Summer" at the beginning of the custom format string, then it actually interprets the double mm's as GetMinute value of the dateTime.  I'd like for the season to remain literal, but the rest of the format string to be interpreted (if that makes sense).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    season = getSeason(dateTimePicker1.Value);
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = convertSeason(season) + " : " + dt_format;
}

public int season = 1;  //set default to summer
public string dt_format = "MMM.d  -h:mm tt";

private int getSeason(DateTime date)
{
    float value = (float)date.Month + date.Day / 100;   // <month>.<day(2 digit)>
    if (value < 3.21 || value >= 12.22) return 3;   // Winter
    if (value < 6.21) return 0; // Spring
    if (value < 9.23) return 1; // Summer
    return 2;   // Autumn
}
private string convertSeason(int value)
{
    string season = "Spring";
    if (value == 1) season = "Summer";
    else if (value == 2) season = "Autumn";
    else if (value == 3) season = "Winter";
    return season;
}

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    season = getSeason(dateTimePicker1.Value);
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = convertSeason(season) + " : " + dt_format;
}
```

Comment: why cannot you append the season string, after you have got the DateTime formatted string?

Comment: Edit every ConvertSeason into this : string season = "'Spring'"

Comment: @ManishMishra Because it's a DateTimePicker?

Answer (score 3):

You need to surround it in a literal string delimiter (for `DateTime` format strings): `'`.

So now your method could be this:

```
private string convertSeason(int value)
{
    string season = "'Spring'";
    if (value == 1) season = "'Summer'";
    else if (value == 2) season = "'Autumn'";
    else if (value == 3) season = "'Winter'";
    return season;
}
```

However, your methods could be improved a bit. So I took the liberty of doing that:

```
private int GetSeason(DateTime date)
{
    //using decimal to avoid any inaccuracy issues
    decimal value = date.Month + date.Day / 100M;   // <month>.<day(2 digit)>
    if (value < 3.21 || value >= 12.22) return 3;   // Winter
    if (value < 6.21) return 0; // Spring
    if (value < 9.23) return 1; // Summer
    return 2;   // Autumn
}
private string ConvertSeason(int value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case 0:
            return "'Spring'";
        case 1:
            return "'Summer'";
        case 2:
            return "'Autumn'";
        case 3:
            return "'Winter'";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: The formatting answer is correct.  However, the ConvertSeason method won't compile, because not all code paths will return a value.